# Define android SeekBar programmatically

Tags: android, android-seekbar

I use SeekBar in my app with ticks. Currently this SeekBar is defined in xml file:

```
<SeekBar
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:theme="@style/Base.Widget.AppCompat.SeekBar.Discrete"/>
```

and it looks ok but I want to define this element programmatically so I've added this instead:

```
SeekBar seekBar = new SeekBar(getContext(), null, R.style.Widget_AppCompat_SeekBar_Discrete);
```

but then the seekBar is invisible. Does anyone know what's wrong? 
It's visible if I use only:

```
SeekBar seekBar = new SeekBar(getContext();
```

but i need ticks.

Answer (score 0):

this works for me:

First, create a **layout** (e.g. layout_seekbar.xml):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<SeekBar
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:theme="@style/Widget.AppCompat.SeekBar.Discrete" />
```

then, you can programmatically add the seekbar in your code:

```
SeekBar bar = (SeekBar)LayoutInflater.from(this).inflate(R.layout.layout_seekbar, null);
bar.setMax(10);
...
bar.setOnSeekBarChangeListener(new SeekBar.OnSeekBarChangeListener() {
                public void onProgressChanged(SeekBar seekBar, int progress, boolean fromUser) {
    ...
    }
    public void onStartTrackingTouch(SeekBar seekBar) {}
    public void onStopTrackingTouch(SeekBar seekBar) {}
});

myLinearLayout.addView(bar);
```

greetings, hope that helps